# How to use \sout{} inside the \title{} using beamer class

Tags: beamer, titles, ulem

The problem is on the title. Here is the minimal code

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage{ulem}

\title{\sout{text}}
\begin{document}
\frame{\maketitle}
\end{document}
```

The errors are

```
Paragraph ended before \let was complete \begin{document}
Undefined control sequence \begin{document}
File ended while scanning use of \KVS@@Process
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The title is also be used in the meta data of the PDF file. There `\sout` is not available and causes the trouble. Use `\texorpdfstring` (of package `hyperref`, loaded by `beamer`) or:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage{ulem}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\sout\relax}

\title{\sout{text}}
\begin{document}  
\frame{\maketitle}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Result of `pdfinfo`:

```
Title:          text
Subject:        
Keywords:       
Author:         
Creator:        LaTeX with Beamer class version 3.27
Producer:       pdfTeX-1.40.14
CreationDate:   Wed Sep 18 17:14:35 2013
ModDate:        Wed Sep 18 17:14:35 2013
...
```